# ¿Es correcto llamar a un método dentro de si mismo?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firestore

Estaba trabajando en una aplicación propia cuando me he visto en la tesitura de que necesito que un método se llame a si mismo, me explico, el método es el siguiente:

```kotlin
fun createOrGetAppointmentFromFirestore(hoursList: List<Hour>, selectedDate: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(dispatchersIO) {
                val hours = mutableListOf<Hour>()
                firebaseFirestore.collection(APPOINTMENTS_PATH)
                    .document(DOCUMENT_DAYS).collection(selectedDate).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        if (it.documents.isNotEmpty()) {
                            it.documents.forEach { document ->
                                document.toObject(Hour::class.java)
                                    ?.let { hour ->
                                        if (hour.available) {
                                            hours.add(hour)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            appointmentAvailableLiveData.postValue(Event(hours))

                        } else {
                            hoursList.forEach { hour ->
                                firebaseFirestore
                                    .collection(APPOINTMENTS_PATH).document(DOCUMENT_DAYS)
                                    .collection(selectedDate).document(hour.time).set(hour)
                            }
                            createOrGetAppointmentFromFirestore(hoursList, selectedDate)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que hace este método es obtener de Firestore un listado de horas disponibles para solicitar una cita, y si no existe ese día en la base de datos, lo creo con las horas disponibles. El caso es que si no existe, cuando las creo, necesito que inmediatamente se vuelva a realizar esta comprobación y lo que se me ha ocurrido es que el método se llame dentro de el mismo. Me funciona pero no se si es la mejor forma de realizar esto.

Comment: no tanto ya que puede fallar el set en el else por problemas de internet y entonces se llamara indefinidamente, no se que problemas puede traer, pero mejor si haces que se ejecute una ves y si falla darle al usuario un boton para intentarlo de nuevo.

Comment: Pero en este caso necesito que se vuelva a llamar a este método, ya que comprueba si el día con las horas disponibles está creado y si no, lo crea, y esto lo muestro en un Recycler View, entonces necesito que esté o no esté, al final el Recycler me lo pinte con las horas que corresponde.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Quieres obtener el dato que se acaba de crear? ¡Pero si ya lo tienes al momento de crearlo! ¿no?

Comment: Quiero obtener el dato que se ha creado en caso de que no exista, el que está en el else, si. ¿Donde se supone que está ese dato?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación oficial de android hay una guía llamada [Coroutines best practices](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices) que deberías leer..

Te nombro las malas prácticas que veo en tu función y adjunto un link a su explicación:

1. usar `GlobalScope` - [Avoid GlobalScope](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope)
2. crear la corrutina en el repositorio - [The ViewModel should create coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#viewmodel-coroutines)
3. retornar el resultado en un `LiveData` - [The data and business layer should expose suspend functions](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#coroutines-data-layer)
4. usar `LiveData` en capas superiores al viewModel - [Don’t use LiveData in Repositories](https://youtu.be/B8ppnjGPAGE?t=617)
5. usar `LiveData` (esto no es mala práctica pero ya no se recomienda usarlo dado que kotlin ofrece nativamente esta feature) - [Is LiveData going to be deprecated?](https://youtu.be/d-GkmHE8G80?t=2317)

Sin embargo lo más importante es lo que comentó A. Cedano, estás trayendo de firestore datos que ya tienes en memoria. **Ese método no necesita llamarse a sí mismo.**

Esta es tu función después de aplicarle buenas prácticas:

```
suspend fun getAvailableHours(hoursList: List<Hour>, selectedDate: String): List<Hour> {
    val collection = firebaseFirestore.collection("$APPOINTMENTS_PATH/$DOCUMENT_DAYS/$selectedDate")
    val hours = collection.get().await().map { it.toObject(Hour::class.java) }
    return if (hours.isEmpty()) {
        hoursList.forEach { hour ->
            collection.document(hour.time).set(hour)
        }
        hoursList
    } else hours.filter { it.available }
}
```

**Nota**: necesitas esta dependencia `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.3` para usar `await()`

Ahora creas la corrutina en tu `ViewModel` y asignas el resultado al `LiveData` (aunque lo más recomendable sería un [StateFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#livedata))

```
fun getAppointment(hoursList: List<Hour>, selectedDate: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val hours = repository.getAvailableHours(hoursList, selectedDate)
        appointmentAvailableLiveData.postValue(Event(hours))
    }
}
```

el [viewModelScope](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471#9930) por default usa el dispatcher `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` en este caso no necesitas cambiar al `Dispatchers.IO` porque de todos modos el sdk de firebase lo va a mover al background thread. De hecho todas las librerías lo hacen porque eso forma parte de las [buenas prácticas](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#main-safe)

Comment: Vale tengo un par de dudas: en primer lugar sobre la función await, su funcionamiento es que no deja que avance hasta que se complete, en este caso, obtener el listado de horas? Y por otro lado, cuando usaba el GlobalScope con el witchContext, le especificaba un Dispatchers, en mi caso el IO al ser una llamada a una base de datos, ¿El viewModelScope sabe a que Dispatchers llamar?

Comment: exactamente, `await` retorna lo que obtendrías dentro de `addOnSuccessListener`. Es decir `await().map` es igual `addOnSuccessListener { it.map }` que también es igual a `addOnSuccessListener { it.documents.map }`. Lo del dispatcher lo agregué a la respuesta

Comment: Y ya que estamos pregunto, cuál es la diferencia entre el addOnSuccessListener y el addOnComplete?

Comment: esto ya no está relacionado con la pregunta principal, sólo una pregunta por post por favor. `addOnSuccessListener` se ejecuta cuando la consulta fue exitosa. `addOnFailureListener` se ejecuta cuando la consulta falla y `addOnCompleteListener` se ejecuta en ambos casos. Usando corrutinas debes usar `try/catch` para saber si ocurrió un error: `try { request.await() } catch (e: Exception) { }`

Comment: Tienes razón, pero me ha surgido la curiosidad sobre la marcha y no tenía un ordenador a mano. De todas formas, dudas resueltas, te lo marco como respuesta.